# Android: Using RadioButton.isChecked() method in Java

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, radio-button

I am trying to create a system that filters a list (in this case, each element is a RelativeLayout element). I am using 3 RadioButton elements in my XML code with the id's radio1, radio2, radio3, that display the top 3, top 5 and top 10 elements respectively. In my java class, I am trying to use the RadioButton.isChecked() method to create the list but for some reason the conditions are never met. Can someone please help me out?

```
private void populateList() { //
    RelativeLayout popList[] = new RelativeLayout[10];


    RadioButton radio1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1); //top 3
    RadioButton radio2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2); //top 5 
    RadioButton radio3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio3); //top 10

    //each represents an elemnent of the list
    popList[0] = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.populate_list1);
    popList[1] = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.populate_list2);
    popList[2] = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.populate_list3);
    popList[3] = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.populate_list4);
    popList[4] = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.populate_list5);
    popList[5] = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.populate_list6);
    popList[6] = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.populate_list7);
    popList[7] = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.populate_list8);
    popList[8] = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.populate_list9);
    popList[9] = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.populate_list10);

    //conditions
    if(radio1.isChecked()) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            popList[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        for(int i = 3; i < 10; i++) {
            popList[i].setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
    else if(radio2.isChecked()) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            popList[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        for(int i = 5; i < 10; i++) {
            popList[i].setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
    else if(radio3.isChecked()) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            popList[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the three radio buttons are in a radio group, you could use [getCheckedRadioButtonId](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup#getCheckedRadioButtonId%28%29)

```
switch (your_radiogroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
    case R.id.radio1:
        //do something
        break;

    case R.id.radio2:
        //do something
        break;

    case R.id.radio3:
        //do something
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: @ShoaibAhmed you are welcome, could you accept or upvote my answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there two issues in your snippet.

First, if you want a good `RadioButtons` behavior, you must group them in a `RadioGroup` in your view ([check this to have more infos](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton)).

After this, you can add a listener to catch which button has changed, like this:

```
// inflate from your view
RadioGroup myRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);

myRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
                switch (i) {
                    case R.id.radio1:
                        // Do something cool
                        break;
                    case R.id.radio2:
                        // Do something cool too
                        break;
                    case R.id.radio3:
                        // Do something else
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
```

I hope it will help you.